# Android Bluetooth Low Energy - Using ScanFilters

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently working on an Android app for Bluetooth Low Energy scanning. In Android 5.0 the option for ScanFilters was introduced. It is working in general, but the number of filters seems to be limited (?)

If I use more than 13 different filters, I cannot find any BLE devices anymore and I get notifications that the app has stopped, even though it continues in the background without finding anything. I don't get warnings or error messages. If I use less filters than 13, everything works just fine. Also the addresses used for filtering do not cause the problem. It comes down to the maximum number as it seems...

The code:
The scan runs in an own Thread:

```
[...]
BluetoothLeScanner myScanner = myBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).build();


//The list for the filters
filters = new ArrayList<>(); 

//mac adresses of ble devices
String[] filterlist = {
                    "D4:B4:C8:7E:D1:35",
                    "C8:86:3A:91:0C:0C",
                    "FD:49:FD:36:04:B4",
                    "E9:91:4A:42:AC:3B",
                    //... some 20 more addresses
};

//adding the mac adresses to the filters list
for (int i=0; i< filterlist.length ; i++) {
    ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(filterlist[i]).build();
    filters.add(filter);
    Log.v("Filter: "," "+ filters.get(i).getDeviceAddress());
}



[...]
while (scanning) {
    final ScanCallback callback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
           Log.v("Callback","in the callback");
    }
    @Override
    public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
        super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
        Log.v("ScanTask", "Some error occurred");
    });

    [...]

    //starting the scan with the filters
    myScanner.startScan(filters, settings, callback);

    //creating some delay and then end the scan
    Thread.sleep(myScanTime);
    myScanner.stopScan(callback);

    [...]
}
```

There seems to be no problem within the code. But why is there a limit on the maximum number of filters? Can someone push me into the right direction or knows a workaround?

**UPDATE:**
removing the app filter in Logcat, it gives me an error message, that might be of help. This is the Logcat:

```
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ EC:2F:08:1E:99:DC
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ F0:5E:4A:36:D5:4F
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ E1:24:88:12:B7:20
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ D1:F7:F3:73:00:43
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ D4:B6:92:2B:7C:EB
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ DE:6D:4A:07:DB:36
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:CD:19
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C3:3B
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C6:F2
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C2:DF
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C6:EA
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C7:7C
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C2:D1
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C7:78
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C7:74
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C2:B8
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:C3:3A
03-25 09:35:32.889  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/Filter:﹕ 00:07:80:1F:CD:2F

03-25 09:35:33.899  18922-19072/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ registerClient() - UUID=9f64337e-6700-4c26-a1f1-64ddc5b874c1
03-25 09:35:33.909  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onClientRegistered() - UUID=9f64337e-6700-4c26-a1f1-64ddc5b874c1, clientIf=6
03-25 09:35:33.919  18166-18180/com.example.install.bluetooth_app D/BluetoothLeScanner﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
03-25 09:35:33.919  18922-18931/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ start scan with filters
03-25 09:35:33.929  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ handling starting scan
03-25 09:35:33.929  18922-18944/? D/BluetoothAdapterService﹕ getAdapterService() - returning com.android.bluetooth.btservice.AdapterService@90e686a
03-25 09:35:33.929  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/ScanTask﹕ Scan is started
03-25 09:35:33.929  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/ScanTask﹕ Filters: 18
03-25 09:35:33.929  18166-19305/com.example.install.bluetooth_app V/ScanTask﹕ ScanTime: 5000
03-25 09:35:33.929  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.939  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ proc btwrite assertion
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterEnableDisabled() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=1
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ allow scan with filters
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 3 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address EC:2F:08:1E:99:DC
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=47
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 4 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.949  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address F0:5E:4A:36:D5:4F
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=46
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=14
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 5 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address E1:24:88:12:B7:20
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=45
03-25 09:35:33.959  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=13
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 6 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address D1:F7:F3:73:00:43
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=44
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=12
03-25 09:35:33.969  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 7 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address D4:B6:92:2B:7C:EB
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=43
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=11
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 8 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address DE:6D:4A:07:DB:36
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=42
03-25 09:35:33.979  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=10
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 9 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:CD:19
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=41
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=9
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 10 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:C3:3B
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.989  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=40
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=8
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 11 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:C6:F2
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:33.999  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=39
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=7
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 12 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:C2:DF
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ onSignalStrengthsChanged signalStrength=SignalStrength: 12 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x4 gsm|lte level=4
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ updateTelephonySignalStrength: hasService=true ss=SignalStrength: 12 99 -120 -160 -120 -1 -1 99 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 -1 2147483647 0x4 gsm|lte
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ updateTelephonySignalStrength: iconLevel=4
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ updateTelephonySignalStrength, No signal level. mPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mDataSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId = com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4 mContentDescriptionPhoneSignal = Volle Signalstärke
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshViews connected={ wifi } level=4 combinedSignalIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mobileLabel=3 AT wifiLabel="W_ISPACE01"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX emergencyOnly=false combinedLabel="W_ISPACE01"xxxxXXXXxxxxXXXX mAirplaneMode=false mDataActivity=0 mPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020440/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mQSPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f020115/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_4 mDataDirectionIconId=0x0/(null) mDataSignalIconId=0x7f020440/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_4_auto_rotate mDataTypeIconId=0x7f0202c9/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_data_connected_h mQSDataTypeIconId=0x7f02011f/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_signal_h mNoSimIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f020495/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mQSWifiIconId=0x7f02012b/com.android.systemui:drawable/ic_qs_wifi_4 mWifiActivityIconId=0x7f020464/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_in mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x1080907/android:drawable/stat_sys_tether_bluetooth
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=38
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=6
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 13 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:C6:EA
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.009  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.009    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=37
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.019    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ refreshSignalCluster - setNWBoosterIndicators(false)
03-25 09:35:34.019    1158-1158/? D/StatusBar.NetworkController﹕ applyOpen
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=5
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 14 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:C7:7C
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=36
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=4
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ set filter index= 15 for clientIf= 6
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ addFilterToController: 0
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-18944/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ add address 00:07:80:1F:C2:D1
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.019  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterConfig() - clientIf=6, action = 0 status = 0, filterType=0, availableSpace=35
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-19015/? D/bt_vendor﹕ op for 7
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-19015/? D/bt_upio﹕ BT_WAKE is asserted already
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.GattService﹕ onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=3
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-18940/? D/BtGatt.ScanManager﹕ callback done for clientIf - 6 status - 0
03-25 09:35:34.029  18922-18944/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: BluetoothScanManager
    Process: com.android.bluetooth, PID: 18922
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
            at java.util.ArrayDeque.removeFirst(ArrayDeque.java:248)
            at java.util.ArrayDeque.pop(ArrayDeque.java:483)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.ScanManager$ScanNative.configureScanFilters(ScanManager.java:738)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.ScanManager$ScanNative.startRegularScan(ScanManager.java:529)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.ScanManager$ClientHandler.handleStartScan(ScanManager.java:212)
            at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.ScanManager$ClientHandler.handleMessage(ScanManager.java:179)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

It looks like there is a variable for available Space for filters which is always set to 15, independent on how many filters are added(?)

```
onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=15
```

It is reduced by one for every filter added and if it falls below 3, the NoSuchElementException is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is obviously a bug in Android 5.0.
With a newer version of Android (tested with 5.0.2) the bug was fixed and the problem does no occur anymore.
Thanks none the less.

Comment: apply a manual filter in the callback...
in pseudocode something like:

`if (filterMap.contains(result.getAddress)){
... do something
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is comment/Suggestion not an answer, due to long post adding it here.

**Chris, I do not see any check in the Bluetooth implementation, which have a limitation of 13 filters,**

Follow below suggestion >

1) Why below code

> while (scanning) {

2) Add your scanResult callback outside as an anonymous class.

3) print scan result in the on ScanResult callback.

4) print failure reason in onScanFailed callback.

5) add logcat(complete) not you filtered one for your app.

6)  why this

> Thread.sleep(myScanTime);

use new Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable{void run(){}},scanTime); instead.

7) Make scanTime of larger value like 1 minute,more filters you use, will take more time to get a callback for scan result.

Comment mentioning me on this answer, i will comeback and follow up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried it, but unfortunately the error continues. Logcat does not print anything, as neither the onScanResult nor the onScanFailed are called, since there is no callback... It seems as if it does not even start scanning.
The logcat just contains sometimes:
BluetoothLeScanner﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6

The while statement with the sleep or wait block is because I need to scan repeatedly every few seconds for a short time. But also eliminating that did not help.

It seems as if too many filters take too long to load for the scan...

Comment: UPDATE:
@AndroidGeek
I added now the logcat in the post above. It hints for a NoSuchElementException, when the "availableSpace" variable goes below a certain limit.

Comment: what is availableSpace?

Comment: I'm not sure, where it is set up but it is in the logcat output: eg


onScanFilterParamsConfigured() - clientIf=6, status=0, action=0, availableSpace=8

Comment: can you send your full code to me, I will try it my end, will make changes as required?

Comment: Thanks for your offer to help. Since this is imbedded in a larger application, I have to ask my boss first who will not be around before monday...
If you're still interested then and he agrees, yeah sure.

Comment: I am not interested to look into your code. I was trying to help, and willing to help if you seek it. :) Happy coding.

Comment: I'm aware of that and appreciate it a lot, thanks. Still, I have to ask first, cause otherwise it could get me in trouble ;)